# SQL retrieve data from 2 different databases

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 databases and 2 Tables

> 1. Database 1 has table : Product
> 2. Database 2 has table : stock

Product has the following rows

```
product_ID, product_code....etc
```

Stock has

```
Product_code, stock_on_hand
```

I need to get the amount of stock when user inserts product_ID please help

Comment: First hint: I assume, you are talking about TABLES, not DATABASES. Second hint: You can JOIN tables. google for that, and if you´r stuck, then ask again (with showing, what you already tried).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help others understand what *you* mean by "I need to get the amount of stock when user inserts product_ID please help."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `JOIN` both tables. Since the tables are hosted on different databases, then you need to prefix the table name with the name of database.

Query:

```
SELECT s.stock_on_hand 
FROM db2.stock s
INNER JOIN db1.product p 
    ON s.product_code = p.product_code
    AND p.product_id = ?
```

You can replace the question mark with the `product_id` that the user is searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing the table with the database name should do the trick:
SELECT DB1.product JOIN DB2.stock;

Answer (score 0):

`select -> join -> where`, is this what you want?

```
select stock_on_hand from product p
inner join stock_on_hand s on s.product_code = p.product_code
where product_id = ??
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct count(Stock.stock_on_hand ) from Stock,Product 
where Product.product_code = Stock.product_code
and Product.product_ID = ?
```

replace `?` to your `product_id`

if the result is lower than expected remove `distinct`